# Embedded TabBarController hit detection bug?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I may have run into a bug, or perhaps I'm just trying to do things in a way that Apple doesn't want me to.

I've created a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/timfuqua/EmbeddedTabBarControllerBug) with a single sample project which mirrors the UI layout of my app, but with different content, that shows the issue. The app should be run in the simulator with iPad Air selected. It is strictly a landscape oriented app.

In this sample project, I haven't written a single line of code. I've replicated the issue using just storyboard. Because of this, I'm thinking the bug is in iOS or it's just not supposed to be done this way.

In the project, I have the starting `UIViewController` embedded in a `UINavigationController`. In the `view controller`, I have some designated space at the top, which has a simple `UILabel` in this sample project, and then a `container view` below it taking up the rest of the space.

Embedded in the `container view` is a `UITabBarController`. The `tab bar controller` links to 2 `UITableViewController`s that have static content in them for simplicity.

The issue now is with the hit detection area of the `UITabBarItem`s of the `UITabBar` of the `tab bar controller`. You can tap just above the actual `tab bar item` (below the red line, but above the `tab bar` section in the image below), which is not supposed to be part of the `tab bar`, and it will switch to the other `table view controller`.

[image: Incorrect_Hit_Detection_Area]

In my real project this is an issue because the cells in the table are interactive, and when the user tries to tap on the bottom cell and they are clearly tapping on the cell and not the `tab bar`, the `tab bar` is "stealing" the touch and switching tabs instead.

There's about 10 points of vertical space that the tab bar is "stealing" the touch input. I've verified this in my real app by making `UITapGestureRecognizer`s for the table and the `UITabBar`, with the parent view controller as the delegate and printing out the touch point y value when the delegate is informed of a tap in `gestureRecognizer(:shouldReceiveTouch)` and in `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin()`.

In my particular sizing, the table receives the tap up to point 710. One point below that, which should be 711, reports as being captured by the `UITabBar`, but the y value isn't 711, it's 720. That continues all the way to 720, which is where the actual `UITabBar` area begins. At point 721, it's correctly reported by the gesture recognizer on the `UITabBar` as being at y value 721. So that entire space between point 711 and 720 is dead space. It's *supposed* to be detected by the table but it's detected by the `UITabBar` instead. But what really makes it "dead" space is that all the points between 711 and 720 all report as point 720, so I can't just special case the touch points between 711 and 720 to map to my table.

Is this a known thing? My theory is that it happens because the `tab bar controller` is embedded in a `container view` that isn't the full size of the screen, and I don't know if having the whole thing embedded in a `navigation controller` has any impact or not.

Comment: Have you found a fix for this?? I am having the same issue

Comment: @D34thSt4lker: No, and I still see the behavior.